# How to access web3Instance when using Truffle's Drizzle

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapps, react, drizzle

I'm working on a dapp with the boilerplate created by running `truffle unbox drizzle` and need to call functions provided by the `web3` instance.

Is there a way to access the `web3` instance object? All we get from drizzle's store is the `state.web3.status` string.

---

**Failed Attempt**

There is `/src/util/web3/web3Reducer.js` and `/src/util/web3/getWeb3.js` but they both appear not to be in use. I tried adding `web3Reducer` to `combineReducers` but always get `null` for the `web3Instance`.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import { drizzleReducers } from 'drizzle'
import web3Reducer from './util/web3/web3Reducer'

const reducer = combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  web3Instance: web3Reducer,
  ...drizzleReducers,
})

export default reducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web3 instance can be accessed via context in components. for more information please check https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react/issues/22